# Can't set inventory on Square item variations

Tags: square-connect

I'm working with Square's connect API, and am trying to sync catalog data with Square. Categories, Items and Item Variations all sync okay, but I'm hitting a snag when trying to set the initial stock level for my item variations.

Here's my rough workflow:

- Create an Item and Item Variation, both via [batch_upsert_catalog_objects](https://github.com/square/connect-ruby-sdk/blob/master/docs/CatalogApi.md#batch_upsert_catalog_objects). Track Inventory and Stock alert threshold are both set (and reflected in the web interface).
- Attempt to `adjust_inventory` with the v1 API, using the same location and Item Variation ID from the previous step.
- Response is: `Cannot find variation with id 'XXX'` (variation ID from the previous step)

### Some clues:

If I retrieve the Item, the variations in the payload do show the same ID 'XXX' as I'm trying to use, so that is correct.

If I `list_inventory` on the Location, the response is empty. If I then change either the initial stock levels, or the stock alert threshold via the web interface, `list_inventory` shows the variation as expected.

If I then repeat the `adjust_inventory` request with the original payload it succeeds.

This feels like something's not being initialised correctly when creating variations via the API - though maybe I'm missing something.

Can anyone shed any light?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the `variation.id` (and not the `item_variation_data.item_id`) when calling AdjustInventory.

Also, you'll probably want to use the `present_at_all_locations` flag when creating the item if not already.